# react native link hangs at "Assets have been successfully linked to your project"

Tags: react-native

after running
**react-native link**

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/appfolder/node_modules (12ms)
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-firebase is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-firebase android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-firebase has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-image-crop-picker is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-image-crop-picker android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-image-crop-picker has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-localization ios dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-localization has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-localization android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-localization has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-maps is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-maps android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-maps has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-vector-icons is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-vector-icons android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-vector-icons has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

^^^^
stuck here.

react: 16.3.2 react-native: 0.55.4

also I'm using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

What can cause this, where to look first?

Comment: where you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: nope I do not. Still have this.